# Is the character "厹," meaning "lecher," commonly used by speakers of any Chinese dialect?

Tags: characters, internet-slang

I've seen this character used to mean "狗公" (“pervert; lecher”) in Cantonese, according to Wiktionary, and pronounced gau2 gung1, as though the single character is representing two characters at once.
It doesn't seem to be included in "The Table of General Standard Chinese Characters" (accessed on http://hanzidb.org/character-list/general-standard) or CC-Canto (a Cantonese dictionary accessed on https://cantonese.org/), but it does give results on Google Images. Does it have a status similar to the character duang1, which has no Unicode representation but is widely recognized by young people due to its use as Internet slang (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duang)? An authoritative source, such as an official dictionary, would be best.

P.S. I also found that 狗公 is used in Gan and Min Nan as well as Cantonese (https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E7%8B%97%E5%85%AC#Chinese). I'm including this in case it is helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The character 厹 is not a formal written form of gau2 gung1 狗公. The character originally refers to an ancient type of Chinese spear and is now obsolete. It's now used as a deliberate "mononym" or "abbreviation" of 狗公 in Cantonese-speaking regions since it comprises 九 gau2 and 公 gung1 (without the 八 above). The purpose is to convey the erotic as well as ironic meaning of 狗公 without making it look too blunt or straightforward. A similar case is the character 夯 used as the "mononym" for 大力.

Comment: Would you say that an average Cantonese speaker would recognize this character?

Comment: Yes. At least among young people.

Answer (score 1):

I have rarely seen厹 used for 狗公, I don't think its possible to be spoken out loud, just rare online slang squishing two characters into one for speed of typing etc.

Compare things like 女干 for messing with characters by radicals-- in this case splitting one character into two for sensorship avoidance.

I wanted to point out that male dog can mean a lot besides lecher, like the english slang simp or just being a scummy guy.  I mention it because I think lecher is actually a less common use to encounter (although thats anecdotal technically since how its used totally depends on what you encounter).

I have also seen the regular term 狗公 used in mandarin, maybe since terms like 老公 have become mainstream its all adopted to mandarin now.